# .NET 3.5: How to host WF runtime in WCF?

Tags: wcf, .net-3.5, workflow-foundation

I need to find a tutorial for hosting the Workflow Foundation Runtime in WCF using .NET3.5.
Does anyone know any good links specifically on this?

UPDATE: Preferably, it should have some code samples on the implementation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've found an article that I've yet to thoroughly review, but it meets my requirement of having code samples and uses .NET 3.5.

**UPDATE:** The article is what I wanted, so I'm marking this as my answer.

[Workflow Services by Matt Milner](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/cc164251.aspx)

Answer (score 0):

Try the MSDN Introduction (first link on Bing, second on Google):

[Introduction to Hosting Windows Workflow Foundation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa663362.aspx)

Comment: Thanks for the article, but from a quick glance I could not find anything specific on WCF hosting.

Comment: You don't host WF in WCF in .NET 3.0/35. You expose a hosted WF workflow via WCF. Hosting WF and esposing workflows as services are two different things. In .NET 4.0 the story has changed dramatically and there is a true integration of the two. However in 3.5, you have to manually integrate services with WF using RecieveActivity and InvokeWebServiceActivity. You still create the WCF service contract and configuration normally, however the implementation is through the workflow.

Comment: Thank you for extra information, but I came to know about WCF hosting through this article about Human Workflow: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-gb/library/cc709416.aspx. As it does not provide sample solution, I came here asking for one. I've found an article that might be the answer to my question, so I hope you can give your comment on it.

Comment: Another difference between WCF hosting a Workflow and a Workflow Web Service are that the latter supports SOAP only. Hosting a workflow in a WCF service is like hosting a workflow in any other managed application.